# C# using Regex to extract a pattern from stock symbol

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to extract a match for a stock symbol from the data feed but we have multiple feeds and the symbols come in with different extensions.

For example:

```
BAC.NY feed 1
BAC.NYY feed 2
BAC.NYNYNY feed 3
BAC.NY.NYNY feed 4
```

I'd like to use Regex to extract BAC.NY and ignore everything after however I'm having a bit of difficulty since I'm a complete newb to Regex.

I've tried:

```
@^.*?(?=.NY)
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Please post your C# code that does not work for you. I think it is not only the regex that is main concern here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following.. `(?=..)` is a lookahead and it wont match the pattern inside it..

```
^.*?\.NY
```

See [RegexStorm Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fm)%5E.*%3F%5C.NY&i=BAC.NY%20feed%201%0D%0ABAC.NYY%20feed%202%0D%0ABAC.NYNYNY%20feed%203%0D%0ABAC.NY.NYNY%20feed%204)

Comment: I'm not sure what OP needs, but it might be better to use `^[^.]*?\.NY` if they want to avoid matching things like "BAC.FL.NY"

Comment: you are right.. but OP dint mention it in his patterns.. thats why I ignored it :)

Comment: I tried that but I'm still getting .NYY and .NYNY  stock symbols can .'s in them however I need all the text up to the .NY and nothing after the .NY

Comment: @Valmorgal how are you extracting the matches?

Comment: My bad guys, I was skipping the results of the match and the event in my code was reassigning the old string back to the symbol name.  Your solution works :)